# Python Animations not working for Fangame Zelda

Tags: python, animation, game-physics

My code is not working the way I want it to. I've tried to program my var to face directions when moving. It's glitched out. Please try to help me. Thank you. When I try to move up, the animation doesnt show, but when i go up and right, then it does up. However, that is the only one that is working any way.......

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
a = 20
# 2 - Initialize the game
pygame.init()
width, height = 720,540
keys = [False, False, False, False]
playerpos=[100,100]
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Zelda")
Background = (245,204,153)
# 3 - Load images
down1 = pygame.image.load('link_down1.png')
down2 = pygame.image.load('link_down2.png')
up1   = pygame.image.load('link_up1.png')
up2   = pygame.image.load('link_up2.png')
left1 = pygame.image.load('link_left1.png')
left2 = pygame.image.load('link_left2.png')
player = pygame.image.load("resources/images/link.png")
tree =    pygame.image.load("resources/images/tree.png")
right = pygame.transform.flip(left1,True,False)

# 4 - keep looping through
while 1:
    # 5 - clear the screen before drawing it again
    screen.fill(Background)
    # 6 - draw the screen elements
    screen.blit(player, playerpos)
    screen.blit(tree, (0,0))
    screen.blit(tree, (0,20))
    screen.blit(tree, (0,40))
    screen.blit(tree, (20,0))
    screen.blit(tree, (20,20))
    screen.blit(tree, (20,40))
    screen.blit(tree, (40,0))
    screen.blit(tree, (40,20))
    screen.blit(tree, (40,40))
    pygame.display.flip()
    # 7 - loop through the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_w:
                keys[0]=True
            elif event.key==K_a:
                keys[1]=True
            elif event.key==K_s:
                keys[2]=True
            elif event.key==K_d:
                keys[3]=True
      if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_w:
                keys[0]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_a:
                keys[1]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_s:
                keys[2]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_d:
                keys[3]=False
        # check if the event is the X button 
      if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            # if it is quit the game
            pygame.quit() 
            exit(0)
        # 8 - Move player
    if keys[0]:
        screen.blit(up1, playerpos)
        playerpos[1]-=0.2
        screen.fill(Background)
        screen.blit(up1,playerpos)
        screen.blit(tree, (0,0))
        screen.blit(tree, (0,20))
        screen.blit(tree, (0,40))
        screen.blit(tree, (20,0))
        screen.blit(tree, (20,20))
        screen.blit(tree, (20,40))
        screen.blit(tree, (40,0))
        screen.blit(tree, (40,20))
        screen.blit(tree, (40,40))
    elif keys[2]:
      screen.blit(down1, playerpos)
      playerpos[1]+=0.2
      screen.fill(Background)
      screen.blit(up1,playerpos)
      screen.blit(tree, (0,0))
      screen.blit(tree, (0,20))
      screen.blit(tree, (0,40))
      screen.blit(tree, (20,0))
      screen.blit(tree, (20,20))
      screen.blit(tree, (20,40))
      screen.blit(tree, (40,0))
      screen.blit(tree, (40,20))
      screen.blit(tree, (40,40))
    if keys[1]:
        screen.blit(left1, playerpos)
        playerpos[0]-=0.2
        screen.fill(Background)
        screen.blit(up1,playerpos)
        screen.blit(tree, (0,0))
        screen.blit(tree, (0,20))
        screen.blit(tree, (0,40))
        screen.blit(tree, (20,0))
        screen.blit(tree, (20,20))
        screen.blit(tree, (20,40))
        screen.blit(tree, (40,0))
        screen.blit(tree, (40,20))
        screen.blit(tree, (40,40))        
    elif keys[3]:
      screen.blit(right, playerpos)
      playerpos[0]+=0.2
      screen.fill(Background)
      screen.blit(up1,playerpos)
      screen.blit(tree, (0,0))
      screen.blit(tree, (0,20))
      screen.blit(tree, (0,40))
      screen.blit(tree, (20,0))
      screen.blit(tree, (20,20))
      screen.blit(tree, (20,40))
      screen.blit(tree, (40,0))
      screen.blit(tree, (40,20))
      screen.blit(tree, (40,40))
    #9
      pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Sorry for the overlong code! ;)

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but you shouldn't have repeated code wherever it can be avoided. Since you're blitting the same trees no matter what key is pressed, you shouldn't have those calls to screen.blit in the if-elif blocks.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to make a Legend of Zelda like game, consider learning about [pygame sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html), and [object oriented programming](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: Ok thank you very much!!

Comment: This question hasn't been answered. Please help me out Something that won't make me change my code

Comment: If you don't want to change your code, then why are you here? Your code has many flaws in it, and it should be completely redone from the ground up. It's clear that you lack the knowledge required to program a game well, which is why I linked you those resources in my last comment.